# Can't use argument in bash date calculation script

Tags: shell-script, quoting, date, arguments

The following bash script won't work. I need to calculate the date depending on the number of days since 14th Oct 1582, where the argument will be the number of days.

```
d="$1"
date -d '14 Oct 1582 + "$d" days'
```

for example the command

```
./datedays.sh 154748
```

should give

```
Wed Jun 21 00:00:00 BST 2006
```

instead it give an error

```
date: invalid date ‘14 Oct 1582 + "$d" days’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use double quotes instead of single quote:

```
date -d "14 Oct 1582 + $d days"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using strong quoting(single quoting) in the script as strong quoting prevents the interpretation of contents inside the single quote except the quote.

Single quoting turns off the special meaning of $ in a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$PATH"
```

Works!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '$PATH'
```

Not Works! Output remains same as input